# selenium : Click on dynamic radio button using python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on a radio button on a web page which is dynamic. I tried classname, xpath and nothing works.

The code that contains the radio button is :

```
<input id="radiofield-1247-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-radio x-form-cb" type="button" hidefocus="true" autocomplete="off" role="radio">
```

There is a label which is adjacent to the button.

```
<label id="radiofield-1247-boxLabelEl" class="x-form-cb-label x-form-cb-label-after" for="radiofield-1247-inputEl">Yes</label>
```

I tried :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio'][@class='#class here'") #.click() and this doesn't work.
```

I tried passing the absolute xpath, which also fails. There is no name or id to do a search for.

Comment: Is the id 'radiofield-1247-inputEl' dynamic value?

Comment: In what way is the button dynamic? How does it change?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying `type="radio"` while on provided `HTML` it's `type="button"`...

Try following `XPath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@id, "radiofield-")][@role="radio"]')
```